# How to use fabric to achieve Goods traceability system?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

[my question, See the following drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8s9A.png)

[image: drawing]

[image]

if I want to achieve a goods traceability system with fabric. How can I achieve it?
This system should include Manufacturers、Wholesaler、Retailer、customer and so on. Their rights are different. How to control their rights? just by edit chaincode?

Comment: What is your question? Where is the code?

Comment: 第一次使用这个网站，可以写中文吗？我刚刚补充了一下内容。我想要用超级账本和物联网结合起来，但是对于fabric只是运行了e2e这个例子。

Comment: Ngomong opo to bocah ini? Please use english..

Comment: I want to use hyperledger and IoT together.  I just running the fabric's e2e this example. If can I control  user rights by just writing smart contracts? The system has many users, different user permissions are not the same

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your case of use and develop a Smart Contract according to it. Then, you should create your own Blockchain. [Here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/), you have more info about it.

For using IoT, you can use [Watson IoT](https://www.ibm.com/internet-of-things/) and integrate it with [Hyperledger](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/).